# Invertir posición par de cadena en Python de mayor a menor

Tags: python

Dada una cadena por medio de input, debo ordernar de mayor a menor los caracteres de la lista según su posición ej. hola (h=0,o=1, l=2, a=3), el resultado debería ser l,o,h,a.

estoy guardando los elementos en otra lista.
este es mi codigo,solo puedo lograr que funcione y arroje la lista en el orden deseado cuando su tamaño es numero impar. No se porque para numero par falla

```
entrada = input("Dame una palabra: ")

salida = ["0"] * len(entrada)

tam = int(len(salida))

i=0

for i in range(0,tam):
    if i%2==0:
        salida[(tam-1) - i]=entrada[i]
        
    else:
        salida[i] = entrada[i]
    
    
print(salida)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Simplemente extrae los caracteres pares por un lado, los impares por otro, invierte estos últimos y combina las cadenas:

`salida = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(entrada[::2][::-1], entrada[1::2] + ' '))).strip()`

### Explicación

Puedes combinar la cadena `entrada` con ella misma pero invertida. No es necesario que conviertas el string a lista para poder iterar por cada uno de los caracteres.

- `entrada[::2]` te devuelve los caracteres pares.
- `entrada[1::2]` te devuelve los caracteres impares.
- `entrada[::2][::-1]` te devuelve los pares pero con el orden invertido.

Si hacemos un [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) con ambas cadenas tendremos un conjunto de tuplas que luego podemos convertir a una única cadena simplemente haciendo [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) de cada tupla y un `join` del resultado de todas ellas.

`''.join(map(''.join, zip(caracteres_pares, caracteres_impares)))`

Esta solución nos genera un problema ya que puede haber más caracteres pares que impares. Podríamos utilizar [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) para crear un conjunto de tuplas tomando como base la más larga de las dos cadenas, pero en este caso, al ser una situación bastante simple y definida (o son de la misma longitud o tiene un único carácter más) podemos añadir un espacio vacío siempre a la cadena de caracteres impares y luego utilizar [`strip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) en la cadena resultante de hacer los joins.

`salida = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(caracteres_pares, caracteres_impares + ' '))).strip()`

### ¿Por qué te falla?

*Tal como comenta Benito B. quizá es una solución demasiado poco básica, así que paso a explicar qué está pasando y cómo solucionarlo en tu código.*

Cuando "reubicas" los caracteres pares estás calculando la posición en base a `tam - 1` pero en el caso de las palabras con un número par de caracteres tienes que añadir una posición más (ya que el último carácter es impar), por lo que la solución podría ser algo así:

```
entrada = input("Dame una palabra: ")

salida = ["0"] * len(entrada)

tam = int(len(salida))

i = 0

for i in range(0, tam):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        if tam % 2 == 0:
            offset = 2
        else:
            offset = 1
        salida[(tam - offset) - i] = entrada[i]
    else:
        salida[i] = entrada[i]

print(salida)
```

Comment: if len(`''.join(map(''.join, zip(entrada[::2][::-1], entrada[1::2] + ' '))).strip()`) >= WOAH: print("WOAH"). Vaya *oneliner* guapo, por cosas así me gusta python. La respuesta es brutal, genial, cojonuda incluso. Pero es una respuesta a un ejercicio de clase donde están usando bucles *normalitos*... si le enseña eso al profesor, lo mismo le *peta la patata*

Comment: Tienes razón, modifico la respuesta con una solución tomando como base su código